# Determine XML schemas and namespaces from schemas

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

**Is it possible to determine which namespaces and schemas should be specified in some XML based on the schemas used to define the elements being used in that XML?**

Given these schemas:

- http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/Egov_ch.xsd
- http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/NameSearch.xsd

what additional information (if any) is required to determine the namespaces and schemas mentioned in the following XML extract <sup>[source](http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/examples/namesearch_req.xml)</sup>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GovTalkMessage xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/govtalkheader http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/Egov_ch.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/govtalkheader"
    xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    xmlns:gt="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <EnvelopeVersion>1.0</EnvelopeVersion>
  <Header>
      [removed for brevity]
  </Header>
  <GovTalkDetails>
    <Keys />
  </GovTalkDetails>
  <Body>
    <NameSearchRequest xmlns="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/NameSearch.xsd" >
        [removed for brevity]
    </NameSearchRequest>
  </Body>
</GovTalkMessage>
```

In the `GovTalkMessage` element, I understand where the 2nd part of `xsi:schemaLocation` comes from, but I'm not sure whether it's possible to determine the first part from the schema itself.

I don't understand where the `xmlns` value has come from in either of `GovTalkMessage` or `NameSearchRequest`. Is it defined somewhere?

`xmlns:dsig`, `xmlns:gt` are mentioned in the `GovTalkMessage` schema, but so is `xmlns:hd`, how do I tell which one's need mentioning in the XML above and which don't?

Why has `NameSearchRequest`'s `xsi:schemaLocation` only got one value? I thought that attribute required two values, separated by a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answers below.

> In the GovTalkMessage element, I understand where the 2nd part of
>   xsi:schemaLocation comes from, but I'm not sure whether it's possible
>   to determine the first part from the schema itself.

The first part of `xsi:schemaLocation` tells what namespace the schema located is associated with. Basically, you are using the namespace http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/govtalkheader for the schema located at http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/Egov_ch.xsd (for any schema used in `xsi:schemaLocation`, it is always the target namespace (see `targetNamespace` attribute) of that schema which comes first and then the location)

> I don't understand where the xmlns value has come from in either of
>   GovTalkMessage or NameSearchRequest. Is it defined somewhere?

`xmlns` is the default namespace. Elements fall under default namespace if they are not qualified by using prefix. In this case the elements `GovTalkMessage` and `NameSearchRequest` fall under the default namespace referred by `xmlns` attributes in your respective schemas.

> xmlns:dsig, xmlns:gt are mentioned in the GovTalkMessage schema, but
>   so is xmlns:hd, how do I tell which one's need mentioning in the XML
>   above and which don't?

If you want to use elements or attributes defined by those namespaces (`xmlns:dsig`, `xmlns:gt`, `xmlns:hd`,...) in your XML, you will declare these namespaces. It's like declaring object references in Java and using attributes of those object references at a later point in your program.

> Why has NameSearchRequest's xsi:schemaLocation only got one value? I
>   thought that attribute required two values, separated by a space.

If you notice the schema http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/NameSearch.xsd, which has no target namespace. This is the reason you don't have namespace but just location in this case. But, you have to use `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` instead of `xsi:schemaLocation` otherwise xml parsers will throw errors. `xsi:schemaLocation` only takes "namespace location" pairs.

Comment: 1) I understand what the first part of `xsi:schemaLocation` indicates, I don't understand where the value `http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/govtalkheader` comes from though. 2) There is no `xmlns` attribute in either schema, unless I'm misunderstanding. 3) So in this instance I don't need to define them? 4) That makes sense thanks.

Comment: 1) If you see my answer the first part is always "target namespace" of the schema associated. 2)xmlns of schema and instance document are different! xmlns of any XML Schema can only have one value which is http ://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema. xmlns of instance document depends on what schema elements you are using. For example, you are using GovTalkMessage element, so xmlns would be targetnamespace for this element schema. 3) You removed some xml code for brevity. As long as you don't use these elements or attributes, you don't need to declare.

Comment: @Jon Do my answers make sense? Let me know if has to be detailed anywhere.

Comment: You are wrong to state `If you notice the schema http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/NameSearch.xsd, which has no target namespace. This is the reason you don't have namespace but just location in this case.` - please correct. If there's no targetNamespace, one must use the xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute; otherwise, one must have only pairs within the xsi:schemaLocation. The linked source XML is just plain wrong.